# How to apply a function to an angularjs expression inside a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angularjs-scope

simple question, I would like to apply a function inside my controller scope to an expression.

This is my HTML inside my controller

```
<p><span ng-if="paginaDetail.pubdate !== '' ">Vanaf {{paginaDetail.pubdate}}</span></p>
```

This is my javascript

```
$scope.formatMysqlTimestampToHumanreadableDateTime = function(sDateTime){
    sDateTime = sDateTime.toString();
    var sHumanreadableDateTime = sDateTime.substring(8, 10) + "/" + sDateTime.substring(5, 7) + "/" + sDateTime.substring(0, 4);
    sHumanreadableDateTime += " " + sDateTime.substring(11, 13) + ":" + sDateTime.substring(14, 16);
    return sHumanreadableDateTime;
};
```

and what I was trying to do is to apply **formatMysqlTimestampToHumanreadableDateTime** to **paginaDetail.pubdate** like this

```
<p><span ng-if="paginaDetail.pubdate !== '' ">Vanaf {{formatMysqlTimestampToHumanreadableDateTime(paginaDetail.pubdate)}}</span></p>
```

or this

```
<p><span ng-if="paginaDetail.pubdate !== '' ">Vanaf {{paginaDetail.pubdate|formatMysqlTimestampToHumanreadableDateTime}}</span></p>
```

but both ways are not correct.

The first method works but on the console i've this error

> Error: [$interpolate:interr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$interpolate/interr?p0=Tot%20%7B%7BformatMysqlTimestampToHumanreadableDateTime(paginaDetail.endpubdate)%7D%7D&p1=TypeError%3A%20sDateTime%20is%20undefined
>   t/<@http://mysite.local/js/libs/angular.min.js:6:443
>   g/r@http://mysite.local/js/libs/angular.min.js:78:354
>   Yd/this.$gethttp://mysite.local/js/libs/angular.min.js:106:161
>   Yd/this.$gethttp://mysite.local/js/libs/angular.min.js:109:285
>   f@http://mysite.local/js/libs/angular.min.js:71:234
>   F@http://mysite.local/js/libs/angular.min.js:75:408
>   ve/http://mysite.local/js/libs/angular.min.js:76:457
>
> http://mysite.local/js/libs/angular.min.js Line 89

and the second one simply doesn't work.

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I can offer an alternative option to controller based actions... this looks like a great scenario for a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

The idea is to use filter the input while it's being put into the html like `{{myDate|format}}`.

The filter is defined like:

```
myApp.filter('format', function () {
   return function (input) {
      //your date parser here
   };
});
```

Or whatever else you wish to do with it. This way you can reuse it without having to put the function in every controller you wish to use it in.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jorgthuijls/QaVLm/2/) you can expand on, to get you going.

**edit** Looking more closely at the error I think your actual problem is that `.pubdate` is not populated (`TypeError: sDateTime is not defined`). Try to put a breakpoint in the function or see what console says.

Comment: Unluckily I can't copy it easily on a fiddle. I just can tell you that I noticed this behavior, with the filter everything works fine as with my first solution, but still wit the same error. so i consol-logged the `input` and i notice that if I apply this function to my `pubdate`, the value is logged four times, the first two times this value is _undefined_ and other two times is the correct value. I just don't understand why it is called *four* times... any clue? because i can solve it like this `if(typeof input === 'undefined'){return "";}` but it's not so smart as a solution...

Comment: Angular keeps looping over the models on your controller to see if there were any changes. This is how the two way binding works. If you loaded this through AJAX or any other method that does not initialize the `.pubdate` value *the first time angular loads* it will go through it first empty, then populated. It will be more than once, in any case. It's called the `$digest` cycle. I'd still recommend the filter... Some info on digest: http://onehungrymind.com/notes-on-angularjs-scope-life-cycle/

Comment: it's managed via an ajax api, you're right, so I assume this check `if(typeof input === 'undefined'){return "";}` may be ok. thank you for the links by the way!

Comment: This actually just works while my function call just didn't seem to and would instead output the string of the function call... Really not sure why.

Answer (score 4):

*This question already has the correct answer, but this may help to understand it better.* For the question "*How to run/apply a function inside an Angular expression*", I can introduce this way,

**Assign your function to $scope.something and run that. Example:**

JavaScript inside your controller:

```
$scope.printMe= function(text){
   return text;
}
```

HTML (expression):

```
<p>{{printMe("Hello!")}}</p>
```

You will get `Hello!` inside your `<p>` tag

Answer (score 3):

Actually your example `{{func(param)}}` works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4418/. Problem is in something else. Try to make a fiddle illustrating your problem.